# Having trouble constructing the correct Linq query syntax in c#.net for a join after join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core

I have troubles creating the correct query for a list of applications I have. I need to display them in a dashboard so consultants can handle the applications. 
These applications can be uploaded by organisations or individuals.

Every consultant is 'owner' of a few organisations and individuals, in the dashboard they should only see the applications from individuals/organisations that they are also the 'owner' of.

The applications table:

```
Application
-----------
ID  |  requestIndividualID   |  requestOrganisationID | ...
```

depending on who made the application the requesters ID will be saved in the table. So `requestIndividualID` or `requestOrganisationID`, one of them will be `null`, the other not.

The Individuals table:

```
Individual
----------
ID  |  name  |  ownerID
```

Now comes the tricky part, the `ownerID` is not on the Organisation table, but on the OrganisationSegment table, something like this:

```
Organisation
------------
ID  |  name  |  city
```

```
OrganisationSegment
-------------------
organisationID  |  ownerID
```

The problem comes when I want to join the Organisation table with the OrganisationsSegment table, since it is possible that the `organisationID` is `null`.

Currently I have this code that is throwing errors:

```
 var applications = from pa in _context.Applications

                 join individu in _context.Individu on pa.requestIndividualID equals individu.ID into IndividuResultList
                 from individu in IndividuResultList.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 join organisation in _context.Organisations on pa.requestOrganisationID equals organisation.ID into organisationsList
                 from organisation in organisationsList

                 join organisationSegment in _context.OrganisationSegment on organisation.ID equals organisationSegment.OrganisationId into organisationSegmentList
                 from organisationSegment in organisationSegmentList.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 select new {Data = new {PortalApplications = pa, individu, organisation, organisationSegment}};
```

After this code I use the result to make a list where I can apply the filter for the owner Id.

When I execute this code, it throws `System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value.` error.

My current solution is making 2 results, one for all the application that have a `requestIndividualID` and one for all the applications with a `requestOrganisationID`.

Then I apply the filter (the specific `ownerID`) to these 2 separate results, and adding the results in a list, since the results came from the same table, thats really easy.
But imo this is a quicky and dirty way of handling it.
I want the correct and clean answer.

Can somebody please help me?
Also i have trouble finding any help on the internet for this, so if you found some info, please link it as well, or tell me how to improve my google skills for issues like this (correct naming of the issue).

Comment: What is the "Companies table"? You also have an undefined `company.ID` in your code. Please try to make your question consistent.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not native speaking english and also not coding with english terms. I had to translate all the tables tables to make more sense on stack overlow.

Comment: No problem, but it needs to at least be consistent. You say the problem is joining `Orginisation` to `OrginisationSegment`, but isn't the problem joining `Orginisation` to `Application` since `requestOrginisationID` might be `null`? Also, is there any particular reason you are making a nested anonymous type for the `select` result?

Comment: I assume every Orginisation has an OrginisationSegment with an `ownerID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is easier if you join the `Orginisation` and `OrginisationSegment` tables first, assuming every `Orginisation` has an `ownerID` in `OrginisationSegment`.

```
var OrganisationsWithOwner = from o in _context.Organisations
                             join os in _context.OrganisationSegment on o.ID equals os.OrganisationId
                             join i in _context.Individu on os.OwnerID equals i.ID
                             select new { o, i };
```

Now you can join with `Individu` and the new `OrginisationWithOwner` and return the one that has a match.

```
var applications = from pa in _context.Applications

                   join indOwner in _context.Individu on pa.requestIndividualID equals indOwner.ID into IndividuResultList
                   from indOwner in IndividuResultList.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join o in OrganisationsWithOwner on pa.requestOrganisationID equals o.o.ID into organisationsList
                   from o in organisationsList.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   select new { PortalApplications = pa, owner = (indOwner != null ? indOwner : o.i), organisation = o.o };
```